Dice results probabilities for indie game roll mechanic
I'd like to calculate the probabilities of success when rolling using my homemade game's unique dice mechanics.

Rolls are made using a stat die + a skill die, each of which can be any of d4, d6, d8, d10, or d12.

Standard difficulties are odd numbers from 5 to 25 (5, 7, 9, 11, .. 25) and a roll that equals or exceeds the difficulty succeeds.

Rolls are made with a pair of dice where one die is equal to the stat die (d4 through d12) and one is equal to the skill die (ditto) with the results of the  two dice added together. A roll of doubles (other than double ones) allows the player to roll the dice again (using the same mechanic) and add the new roll to the total. These "explosions" can further explode. There is a caveat: if any roll comes up as double ones, rolling stops and the final result becomes 2 regardless of how many explosions have already been rolled. Explosion rolls are not mandatory and players can stop rolling at any point (but their last roll is still counted... this cannot be used to retroactively "negate" a roll). There are additional benefits ("Crits") for every 3 points by which the roll exceeds the target number (up to 9 greater, or 3 degrees of Crit), so when deciding whether or not to continue rolling in hopes of a Crit must be weighed against the possibility of rolling double ones and turning the roll into a "Fumble."

The mechanic is further complicated by an advantage/disadvantage system. Advantage and Disadvantage ("Adv" and "Dis") each come in degrees of 1 to 3 and cancel each other out on a one-to-one basis, (eg One Adv plus one Dis would totally cancel out for a "normal" roll, while 2 Adv plus 1 Dis would yield a roll with a net degree of Adv 1. Remember that neither of the initial Adv or Dis values can exceed 3.) For each degree of Adv, the roll's Target Number ("TN") is decreased by 2 and each degree of Dis increases the TN by 2. if Adv reduces the TN below 5, the player may take an automatic success or roll against TN 5 in hopes of exceeding the TN for a Crit along with the possibility of failure or even rolling double ones and fumbling.


I would like to determine the percentage odds of success for each dice combination (d4+d4, d6+d4, d8+d4, .. d12+d12 ... note that for this purpose there is no functional difference between d4+d6 and d6+d4 or any similar combination of two different dice) against TNs from 5 to 40 (to account for Dis) and including even numbers (to account for degrees of Crit that exceed the TN by 3, 6, or 9). For the purposes of this calculation, assume that the player stops rolling once they have achieved a success rather than "pressing their luck" for a higher roll.
I know that...

Odds of any particular individual roll (such as 1+1, 1+2, 2+1, etc.) occurring are 1 in size of the first die multiplied by the size of the second die. (Continuing the previous example of d4+d12, each roll result has a 1 in 4*12 or 1/48 chance.)

The odds of a rolling doubles is dependent on the size of the smaller die. (Rolling d4+d12 will not result in doubles higher than double 4s.) d4+d12 allows only 3 possible beneficial doubles (3 in 48, or 6.25%) whereas d6+d10 has 5 such possibilities (5 in 60, or 8.33%) while d8+d8 has 7 (7 in 64, or ~10.94%).


I am seeking any one of...

a formula or set of formulae for the odds of success

a spreadsheet utilizing such formulae

an AnyDice or Python program that calculates and displays the probabilities



Solution in Python
Using my Icepool Python probability package, we can express this as a "forward" process (as opposed to an explicitly recursive calculation):
from icepool import d4, d6, d8, d10, d12, map

LIMIT = 40

def explode_pair(state, roll_a, roll_b, safe):
    total, done = state
    if done:
        return total, done
    if roll_a == 1 and roll_b == 1:
        return (max(total, 2) if safe else 2), True  # fumble
    result = min(total + roll_a + roll_b, LIMIT)
    return result, (result == LIMIT or roll_a != roll_b)

output(map(explode_pair, (0, False), d6, d8, True, repeat=None).marginals[0])

You can try this in your browser here.
Stopping strategy
Suppose you have a target TN in mind ahead of time (base TN + advantage/disadvantage + desired number of crits) and you only care about whether you reach that TN or not. In this case, you would not gain any additional benefit if you were able to retroactively cancel a fumble -- if you exploded and fumbled, that meant that you hadn't reached the target TN in the previous roll, and thus would not have succeeded even if you had chosen to stop. This is represented by the safe parameter in the code: if safe is True, the x-axis of the "at least" graph represents the chance of reaching each TN provided you pre-commit to that specific TN before rolling.
If safe is False, there is no pre-commitment: you explode at every opportunity and the x-axis is simply what you rolled.
repeat
Here repeat=None finds the absorbing distribution as long as the number of possible states is finite and not too large. This can even handle cases with cycles, though the algorithm is only a relatively crude implementation of Gaussian elimination. In this case there are no cycles, and in fact we are guaranteed to stop within 14 steps, so we could have chosen a fixed number of repeats instead.

That's what I came up with:
function: explodeinner N:n and M:n dice A:d and B:d {
 if N=1 & M=1 { 
  result: -1000
 }
 else {
  if M=N {
    result: M+N+[explodeinner A and B dice A and B]
   }
  else {
   result: M+N
  }
 }
}
function: filter N:n {
 if N<=2 { result: 1} else { if N>25 {result: 25} else {result: N} }
}
function: oddsteps N:n {
 result: (((N+1)/2)*2)-1
}
function: explodes A:d and B:d {
 result: [oddsteps[filter[explodeinner A and B dice A and B]]]
}
set "maximum function depth" to 5

output [explodes d6 and d8]

(the point of -1000 is to make the roll negative regardless of any other rolls, simulating the 1, 1 = fail, no matter what else was rolled - ugly, but the only way I could make it to work)
Results:
Output of 1 means fumble, output of 3 means standard failure for all possible DCs
The recursion depth is set to 5, increasing it to 6 gives negligible difference.
d6 and d8 (8.45 / 4.11)
#   %
1   2.33
3   8.33
5   16.67
7   23.09
9   21.35
11  13.50
13  7.70
15  1.73
17  1.71
19  1.40
21  0.96
23  0.54
25  0.68

Crits and adv/dis are not taken into account:
Crits do not change between success and failure, so they do not affect the probabilities. Adv and dis I might add later on but for now, each step of adv/dis simply means you have to look at success for check one step easier/harder.

Thanks. That seems to work well. can we add a check for a fumble? in this case a negative result.

And, yeah, Adv and Dis merely adjust the target number now. Originally each degree of either added a d6 to the first roll. For Adv you got to pick which two rolls to use (normally the higher two, but possibly choosing two lower ones that were doubles in hopes of good explosions). Any explosions would use only the two chosen dice.
Dis required you to use the two lowest dice.
typing it up, I realized how that would be next to impossible to code and changed the way they worked.

@Rob "check for Fumble" - you mean to separate standard failure with fumble failure?

Any result of 2 (or less, thanks to the -1000 workaround) would be a fumble. so...
2 or less = fumble
3 or 4 = autofail (since 5 is the lowest TN)
5+ are possible successes

@Rob I've separated fumble and standard failure.
